# How to get the text that is separated by a comma after a keyword

Tags: python, regex, parsing

so I have a string that has multiple patterns like

`s1 = "foo, bar"`

`s1 = "x, y"`

`s2 = "hello, hi"`

`s3 = "bar, foo."`

I'm wondering how I can get the strings that are separated by a comma (insert random text here).

So from this example, I want to get strings `["foo","bar"]` and `["x","y"]` when I'm looking for `"s1"`, and `"hello"` & `"hi"` when I look for `s2`, etc.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Let's assume using `.split(',')` is impractical due to a large number of commas outside this specific pattern I listed

Comment: `my_string.split(',')` returns a list of each element seperated by commas

Comment: I updated my question. Let's assume using .split(',') is impractical due to a large number of commas in the string outside this specific pattern.

Comment: `re` module on Python

Comment: How can I use it in this instance?

Comment: A re the semicolons in your actual string? Could you give us your real string and real expected output?

Comment: Please be specific of *where* these pattern occur. If `split` does not work you probably meant to write something like *"blablabla text1, text2 blablabla"*?

Answer (score 1):

The question was edited, but for for the original string:

```
"s1: foo, bar s1:x,y s2:hello, hi s3: bar, foo."
```

You could use a pattern to match the specific part and then use re.split to split on a comma and optional space.

```
\bs1: ?(\w+(?:, ?\w+)*)
```

*Explanation*

- `\bs1: ?` Match `s1:` and optional space
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+(?:, ?\w+)*` Match 1+ word chars, optionally repeat comma, optional space and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nh59tQ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1teO7l)

*Example code (python 3)*

```
import re

s = "s1: foo, bar s1:x,y s2:hello, hi s3: bar, foo."

def findByPrefix(prefix, s):
    pattern = rf"\b{re.escape(prefix)}: ?(\w+(?:, ?\w+)*)"
    res = []    
    for m in re.findall(pattern, s):
        res.append(re.split(", ?", m))        
    return res

print(findByPrefix("s1", s))
```

*Output*

```
[['foo', 'bar'], ['x', 'y']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
my_string.split(',')
```

It should return a list of every element.

Comment: I updated my question. Let's assume using .split(',') is impractical due to a large number of commas outside this specific pattern I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `re` module to split a string by a given delimiter:

```
import re

re.split(", ", my_string)
```